# Facebook API: Getting photos that have a comment containing a a string

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm implementing a pseudo hash-tagging system for the company I work at with their customer's facebook photos. A customer can upload a photo to the page, and a page admin can tag it with the hashtag for a product.

What I am trying to do is get all photos from the page that have a certain tag in the comments (for instance, get all photos from the company page with a comment containing only '#bluepants').

I am trying to make sure the Facebook API handles the heavy lifting (we'll cache the results), so I'd like to use FQL or the Graphs API, but I can't seem to get it working (my SQL is quite rusty after relying on an ORM for so long). I would prefer if it outputs as many results as possible, but I'm not sure if FB lets you do more than 25 at once.

This is going to be implemented in a sinatra site (I am currently playing around with the Koala gem, so bonus points if I can query using it)

Could anyone give me some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got something like this working in FQL/PHP. Here is my multiquery.

```
{'activity':
   "SELECT post_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGE_ID AND 
      attachment.fb_object_type = 'photo' AND created_time > 1338834720 
      AND comments.count > 0 LIMIT 0, 500",
  'commented': 
    "SELECT post_id, text, fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id IN 
      (SELECT post_id FROM #activity) AND AND (strpos(upper(text), '#HASHTAG') >= 0", 
   'accepted': 
     "SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, attachment, place, created_time, likes 
       FROM stream WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #commented) 
       ORDER BY likes.count DESC", 
   'images': 
     "SELECT pid, src, src_big, src_small, src_width, src_height FROM photo 
        WHERE pid IN (SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #accepted)",
   'users':
      "SELECT name, uid, current_location, locale FROM user WHERE uid IN 
        (SELECT actor_id FROM #accepted)",
   'pages':
     "SELECT name, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #accepted)",
   'places':
      "SELECT name, page_id, description, display_subtext, latitude, longitude 
         FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT place FROM #accepted)"
 }
```

To break this down:

- `#activity` gets all stream objects created after the start date of my campaign that are photos and have a non-zero comment count. Using a LIMIT of 500 seems to return the maximum number of posts. Higher or lower values return fewer.
- `#commented` finds the posts that have `#HASHTAG` in the text of one of their comments. Note, I'm not looking for a `#`, which is a reserved character in FQL. Using it may cause you problems.
- `#accepted` gets the full details of the posts found in #commented.
- `#images` gets all the details of the images in those posts. I have it on my todos to refactor this to use `object_id` instead of `pid` and try using the new `real_width` specification to make my layout easier.
- `#users` and `#pages` get the details of the actor who originally posted the item. I now know I could have used the `profile` table to get this in one query.
- `#places` gets the location details for geo-tagged posts.

You can see this in action here: http://getwellgabby.org/show-us-a-sign

Comment: Thanks! For some reason though, activity only returns the id and created_time for comments (and only the first photo, which has a very large amount of comments - none of which have a hashtag). None of the other queries return anything because the comments don't have a hashtag…

Comment: scratch that, it was because i missed that you had an uppercase function that I didn't want. This works almost perfectly, but it only returns one comment and subsequently, only one photo. Is this intended or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The stream table is consistently inconsistent. I can't speak about your stream, but using a slightly modified version of this query, I can usually return between 10-50 photos.

Comment: Thanks anyway. It's too inconsistant, so we're going to scrape it ourselves. Thanks for your help!